# Extract content between two patterns from a file

Tags: bash, awk, pattern-matching, extract

I want to extract the following content between `The SUMMARY` and `End processing summary for first university` as well as the `The SUMMARY` and `End processing summary for second university`

This is my file:

```
Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...

The SUMMARY
Total students: 1200
Total teachers: 10
Total subjects: 20
Total attendance: 12000
End processing summary for first university

Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...

The SUMMARY
Total students: 1500
Total teachers: 12
Total subjects: 15
Total attendance: 20000
End processing summary for second university

Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...
```

The following works great:

```
firstUniversity=$(awk '/The SUMMARY/ && ++n == 1, /End processing summary for first university/' < theLog.log)

secondUniversity=$(awk '/The SUMMARY/ && ++n == 2, /End processing summary for second university/' < theLog.log)
```

**However**, sometimes either `the summary for first university` or `the summary for second university` is missing and the above code does not work.

**First university block is missing**

```
Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...
Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...

The SUMMARY
Total students: 1500
Total teachers: 12
Total subjects: 15
Total attendance: 20000
End processing summary for second university

Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...
```

**Or the second university block is missing**

```
Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
...
...

The SUMMARY
Total students: 1200
Total teachers: 10
Total subjects: 20
Total attendance: 12000
End processing summary for first university

Logs here
...
...
...
More logs here
```

Any solution using either the `sed` or the `awk` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different awk approach:

```
cat extract.awk

/The SUMMARY/ {                                       # match starting line
  s = $0                                              # set s to current line
  p = 1                                               # set flag p to 1
}
p {                                                   # if flag p is set
   s = s ORS $0                                       # keep adding lines to s
}
$0 ~ "End processing summary for " kw " university" { # when we find end line
   print s                                            # print full text
   p = 0                                              # reset p to 0
}
```

Then use it as:

```
firstUniversity="$(awk -v kw='first' -f extract.awk inputFile)"
secondUniversity="$(awk -v kw='second' -f extract.awk inputFile)"
```

Without using a awk script file:

```
firstUniversity="$(awk -v kw='first' '/The SUMMARY/{s=$0; p=1} p{s = s ORS $0}
$0 ~ "End processing summary for " kw " university"{print s; p=0}' inputFile)"

secondUniversity="$(awk -v kw='second' '/The SUMMARY/{s=$0; p=1} p{s = s ORS $0}
$0 ~ "End processing summary for " kw " university"{print s; p=0}' inputFile)"
```

Comment: is it possible to not use the file?

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please also explain very short how it works?

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. In this solution for clarity I had created `found_university` variable.

```
awk '
/The SUMMARY/{
   found_summary=1
   val=found_university=""
}
/End processing summary for first university|End processing summary for second university/{
   found_university=1
   if(found_university && found_summary){
     print val ORS $0
   }
   val=found_university=found_summary=""
}
found_summary{
   val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
'  Input_file
```

One could try following which doesn't use variable `found_university` and simply checks condition for university string occurrence.

```
awk '
/The SUMMARY/{
   found_summary=1
   val=""
}
/End processing summary for first university|End processing summary for second university/{
   if(found_summary){
     print val ORS $0
   }
   val=found_summary=""
}
found_summary{
   val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed level explanation for above code. Please scroll little right to see explanation :)

```
awk '                                                                                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/The SUMMARY/{                                                                                    ##Checking condition if line has string The SUMMARY then do following.
   found_summary=1                                                                                ##Setting found_summary as 1 here.
   val=""                                                                                         ##Nullifying variable val here.
}
/End processing summary for first university|End processing summary for second university/{       ##Checking condition if university string present in line then do following.
   if(found_summary){                                                                             ##Checking condition if found_summary is SET then do following.
     print val ORS $0                                                                             ##Printing variable val ORS and current line here.
   }
   val=found_summary=""                                                                           ##Nullifying variables val and found_summary here.
}
found_summary{                                                                                    ##Checking condition if found_summary is SET then do following.
   val=(val?val ORS:"")$0                                                                         ##Keep concatenating current line in val value.
}
'  Input_file                                                                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I believe OP wants 2 values in separate bash variables.

Comment: @anubhava, oh sorry I missed it, lemme fix it now.

Comment: @anubhava, I have done it by making `IFS='~'` and sending output of awk command to an array later we could fetch values of arrays like `array[0]`, `array[1]` etc but again question comes I have set `~` so what happens if that character comes in Input_file, that is where I am stuck as of now and looking into it- just an update here.